# How do you find the embed code for videos on a Website when it doesn't show in the source code?

Tags: video, embed

I have permission from American Dental Association to deep link to videos on their site (www.ada.org/50.aspx) to my site, but they don't provide the embed code. I copied their source code, but all I get is the player without the videos. They use Delve Networks (Limelight) to host their videos. Someone suggested using Burp Suite by first setting up my browser to use a local proxy server on port 8080, and then going to the ADA site, playing the videos, and viewing the results in Burp. Should I be looking for names of swf files? I haven't found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see where the actual video is coming from. You can use either network panel in chrome or activity viewer in safari browser. I looked at it and it turns out the site itself is embedding the videos from a 3rd party solution delvetnetworks. Go to this URL

http://assets.delvenetworks.com/player/fp10loader.swf?playerForm=471230a733394b05b56328e761a093d6&deepLink=true&channelListId=5fcc7f2eafba49a1bd612fb6b96b0dc0&53990469

you can see the videos from this directly, you can embed the content of this url inside your website in the size you want, hope it helps

Comment: Where would I place that URL within the code that begins with <h3>Dental Minutes</h3>?

Comment: use an iframe, in your site, just add this. <iframe src="http://assets.delvenetworks.com/player/fp10loader.swf?playerForm=471230a733394b05b56328e761a093d6&deepLink=true&channelListId=5fcc7f2eafba49a1bd612fb6b96b0dc0&53990469" />

Comment: i am sorry if you couldnt see that comment fully just add <iframe src="that_url_i_pasted" /> after that <h3>Dental Minutes</h3>

Comment: Wow, that's excellent. Thanks a LOT!!! Now I just need to figure out how to change the size.

Comment: Thats no big deal, change a bit to <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src...blah blah/> adjust those 100% to width and height you like

Comment: You've been a big help!!! Thank you very much!!! I'll study iframes, because height of 100% doesn't change the height, but the width did change. I have been searching for an answer for several days on how to incorporate those videos into my site!